# Delete duplicates from XML but keep lines when attribute value is blank

Tags: powershell

I have an XML file of below structure and want to delete all lines that contain a duplicate VATRegistrationNumber but I still need to keep all lines that contain  an empty VATRegistrationNumber.

```
<Suppliers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:supplier:erp-integration">
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008755" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PETER GOW" City="LISMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="60185579027" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008754" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="DANIEL PETRUSHNKO" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="52216736429" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008753" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEOPLE2PEOPLE" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008752" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEARL CLEANING" City="WOONONA" VATRegistrationNumber="29169648828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008751" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATTO'S PAINTLESS" City="TAMWORTH" VATRegistrationNumber="30482156828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008750" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATRICK ST CLINIC" City="PENGUIN" VATRegistrationNumber="53220182389" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008749" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="MITCHELL PAISH" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="42091590585" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008748" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PACNET INTERNET" City="MELBOURNE" VATRegistrationNumber="69085213690" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008747" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="NICHOLAS J OWENS" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="32168537004" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008746" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="JOHN O'SULLIVAN" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="51136629180" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008745" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="OSTAR ELECTRICAL" City="BANGALOW" VATRegistrationNumber="47196051022" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008756" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PKL COURIERS" City="PALM BEACH" VATRegistrationNumber="90690407812" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008788" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="MICHAEL JOHN MCMANUS" City="COBAR" VATRegistrationNumber="51136629180" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008787" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="MOREE PROPERTY" City="MOREE" VATRegistrationNumber="52216736429" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008786" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="PATRICIA GOULD" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008785" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="KAREN DRUCE" City="Warrimoo" VATRegistrationNumber="42091590585" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008784" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="SOLAR SOLUTIONS" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="65164304054" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008783" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ST GEORGES CHURCH" City="Hurstville" VATRegistrationNumber="79115673239" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008782" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="SHARED VALUE" City="PORT MELBOURNE" VATRegistrationNumber="32168537004" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008781" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALLEN KIRK" City="STUARTS POINT" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008775" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="NATIONAL REMOVALS" City="ASHMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="19748626605" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008774" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="INLAND CONTAINER" City="DUBBO" VATRegistrationNumber="78001638777" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008814" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="CTARS PTY LTD" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="59603816593" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008813" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="JENNY &amp; MARSH" City="LAMBTON" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008812" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ACDMA CENTRE" City="Canley Vale" VATRegistrationNumber="58002378731" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008999" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="CENTRAL HOTEL" City="Sydney" VATRegistrationNumber="47196051022" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008969" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALES LICHNER" City="BANGOR" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
</Suppliers>
```

Here is the powershell code that I have so far but it is currently skipping lines containing an empty VATRegistrationNumber which I need to keep.

```
[xml]$myfile = [xml](Get-content "input.xml")
$nodesToRemove = $myfile.suppliers.childnodes | Group-Object VATRegistrationNumber |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 }
    
$nodesToRemove | Foreach-Object {
    $myfile.suppliers.RemoveChild($_)
}
#save XML
$myfile.Save("result.xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop also deleting nodes with empty `VATRegistrationNumber` attributes, you can do as below:

```
# use full, absolute paths for these
$inputFile  = 'X:\somewhere\input.xml'
$outputFile = 'X:\somewhere\result.xml'
# load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xmlDoc.Load($inputFile)

# group nodes on the not empty VATRegistrationNumber attribute and store only those that have duplicates
$nodes = $xmlDoc.suppliers.childnodes | Where-Object { $_.VATRegistrationNumber -match '\S' } | 
         Group-Object VATRegistrationNumber | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }
# loop over the childnodes
foreach ($group in $nodes) {
    $group.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
        [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
    }
}
# finally save the new xml
$xmlDoc.Save($outputFile)
```

Comment: Thanks Theo for your help. I have tried the code and the empty VATRegistrationNumber are now in the result file but so are all other entries. No duplicated VATRegistrationNumber is removed anymore. The input and the result file are now identical. I don't see where the mistake in the code is.

Comment: @Jana Ah yes, there were two typos in there, sorry for that. I now also changed the code a bit with an extra `Where-Object` clause to filter away all nodes with an empty `VATRegistrationNumber` attribute. This means the loop doesn't have to check for that in the loop (should save some time)